# dynamically allocate memory for pointer to array of structure

Tags: c, memory-management, structure

hi i have this structure

```
typedef struct STUDENT
{
    char studName[20];
    int timeEnter;
    int timeUpdate;
}STUDENT;
```

and the local pointer to array of structure

```
STUDENT *studArr[100];
```

I'm trying to allocate memory for the structure by doing reading in the first line of the file then use it to allocate memory for the structure.

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", &first);
**studArr = (STUDENT**) malloc(sizeof(STUDENT*)*first);
```

I got an error saying that no operator "=" matches these operands on the allocation line

why am I gettting the error, what did i do wrong here?

thank in advance

Comment: why `**studArr` and why `sizeof(STUDENT*)`?

Comment: because i want to allocate pointer to structure so i can point to structure member later on

Comment: do not cast malloc() return type...

Comment: @akp That's the least of his issues. And not even a real issue.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart but i have posted the answer too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing things, it looks like you're declaring an array of pointers, when all you need is a single pointer. Note that as long as you're indexing properly, a pointer to "one" `struct` is the same as a pointer to a hundred.

You should probably have:

```
STUDENT *studArr;
```

then, once you know how many you need (I'm assuming `first` is the number of students to allocate room for):

```
studArr = malloc(first * sizeof *studArr);
```

Also note that [no casting is needed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: for some reason the compiler that I'm using asked to cast the malloc function to STUDENT*, It maybe because I'm using a c++ compiler

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allocate an array of 100 students, you have two choices:

```
struct STUDENT
{
    char studName[20];
    int timeEnter;
    int timeUpdate;
};


struct STUDENT studArr1[100];

... OR ...

struct STUDENT *studArr2 = (struct STUDENT *)malloc (sizeof (struct STUDENT) * 100);
```

If you just want a pointer, you can say:

```
  struct STUDENT *p = studArr1;
```

PS:

I deliberately left the "typedef" stuff out so as not to confuse the basic issue (struct vs. array of struct vs pointer to array of struct).

Comment: how can i be able to allocate if i have something like this STUDENT *studArr[100];?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined an array of pointers to struct, not a pointer to an array of struct. The memory for the array is already allocated, as a global array.

The type of `**studArr` is STUDENT, and hence is not compatible with the expression to the right of the assignment operator, which is casted to `(STUDENT**)`.

You probably meant:

```
STUDENT **studArr;
```

[...]

```
fscanf(fp, "%s", &first);
studArr = (STUDENT**) malloc(sizeof(STUDENT*)*first);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using STUDENT *studArr[100]; then it means you have allocated the memory for 100 pointers for STUDENT structure type.

so for allocating the memory you should try.

```
studArr =malloc(sizeof(struct STUDENT)*first);
```

then you can access all the allocated members as `studArr[i] ....so on`.

Comment: thank I found another question that have the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397728/c-pointer-to-array-of-pointers-to-structures-allocation-deallocation-issues

Answer (score 0):

You're not exactly clear on what your overall goal is.

First of all, you want to use `%d` if you want to read in an integer:

```
int count;
if (fscanf(fp, "%d", &count) != 1) { // error... }
```

Next, don't use `STUDENT` as both the struct name and the typdef. Just leave the struct name out:

```
typedef struct
{
    char studName[20];
    int timeEnter;
    int timeUpdate;
} student_t;
```

Now, you're going to want just a pointer to an array of `student_t`s:

```
student_t* student_array = NULL;
```

Finally, allocate that array:

```
student_array = malloc(count * sizeof(student_t));
```

---

Now you can use it, like:

```
strncpy(student_array[0].studName, "Bobby", 20);
```

Or get a pointer to an individual student:

```
student_t* bob = &student_array[1];
bob->timeEnter = 42;
```