# How to define an array having 2 columns of strings

Tags: c

Is it possible to define and initialize 2 columns of strings with a single array? I mean I want to initialize an array with following values:
{"Cp", "Mu", "H", "Si"}  ->  Column-1
{"Specific Heat", "Viscosity", "Enthalpy", "Surface Tension") -> Column-2
How can I do it? Will it be easier by using pointers?

Comment: Like an array of structures with two members? Or an array of two arrays of strings?

Comment: Are the columns related? From the text it looks more like you want a `struct` of two "strings".

Comment: something like `const char *array[2][4] = {{"Cp", "Mu", "H", "Si"}, {"Specific Heat", "Viscosity", "Enthalpy", "Surface Tension"}};`?

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use an array of a structure, as so,

```
struct property{
char col1[size_of_row];
char col2[size_of_second_row];
};
struct property list[size_of_list];
```

Or, rather, if the number of elements in the list is not known, you could use an array of pointers, with each pointer pointing to a node with a property under column 1 and column 2. You can refer to [dynamic array of dynamically allocated structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397728/c-pointer-to-array-of-pointers-to-structures-allocation-deallocation-issues)

Comment: I have written following code:

  3 struct Property {
  4     char *Sym[4];
  5     char *SymName[4];
  6 };
  7 static const struct Property Props = { {"A",  "Helmholtz Free Energy",
  8     "Cp", "Specific Heat at Constant Pressure", NULL},
  9              {"Cv", "Specific Heat at Constant Volume",
 10     "D",  "Density", NULL}
 11 };
...
58     while (Props.Sym[i])
59         printf("%s\n", Props.SymName[i++]);

After printing 1st two values it displays "Segmentation fault" - why?

Comment: Segmentation fault generally occurs if you try to access memory, which does not lie in the declared region.So, your code should run, print out the 4 values of Props.SymName[i] and then show segmentation fault since you have declared Sym and SymName as arrays with 4 indices. I have tried running the code. Provide an `i < 4` for the while condition. Basically limit the while loop to declared size of the array.